# Parse and send Java logs to the ELK 7.3

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

Using Elasticsearch 7.3 on CentOS 7 and Java version 11, I need to parse and find specific Error/Exception in Java Application log files, wondering if I should use Filebeat or Metricbeat to parse and ship some text patterns in log files to Elastic?

Sample code to show how to parse/ship specific error pattern is very helpful.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Filebeat is for logs.
2. To make your life easier, I'd use a structured log format. We have just released https://github.com/elastic/java-ecs-logging which ties right into Elasticsearch and also provides the right Filebeat configuration.

Comment: The instruction and steps are a bit complicated for me since I'm not an ELK expert, is there any simple introduction how to pars and ship the logs using your library?

Comment: Since this is a common question I've tried to put something together — hope it helps: https://xeraa.net/videos/nginx-spring-boot-logging-best-practices/